# SourceTree Git Graph looks Wrong

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to SourceTree and relatively new to Git (have been using subversion for years).

I just joined a project and wanted to do a quick test to make sure I could make a feature properly and merge it back in. I seem to be following everything in the tutorial correctly. I checkout the project, I click on Git Flow, start a feature, make a change, commit the change to my feature. I am looking at the different views and the graph seems to either be wrong, or the way the project has been setup is wrong, or... I don't know. It should be obvious from the picture.

[image: Screenshot]

On the develop branch I would have expected the line to be purple and for my committed change with message "Test" branched off from this. You can see someone has merged in the develop branch to the master, is this malpractice? Even if changes from develop go into master, shouldn't the purple line stay separate? Should the graph actually look like this and I'm misunderstanding something? What the hell is going on?

Cheers!

p.s. the tutorial is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lSdqrs2f5c if anyone's interested.

Comment: Nah, that's just how it looks. Sourcetree just likes to be different.

Comment: What is your problem? the color of the line??

Comment: Well to me when looking at the develop branch I'd expect the current line to be purple. The feature branch would be spanned off from it (like the yellow line). Once I merge will the view change? What's the point of making a feature if it doesn't actually branch? Why aren't the master and develop branches separate?

Comment: Look at 2:59 in the video I added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's displaying my feature branch as the master branch is because there are no changes to either the master branch or the develop branch that make it different from my feature. Once I had pulled some updates today, I could see it had branched out.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you're looking for is "fast-forwarding". Disabling it, creates a commit even if there's no changes with the branch you're merging.

There's an option in sourcetree to force --no-ff on git calls.
Tools > Options > Git > Do not fast-forward etc.

I advise you to use no-ff option if you're using GitFlow. This will effect your further commits, however there's no effect for the previous ones.